# Chrome CSS inspector won't let me type in new values

Tags: css, google-chrome, web-inspector

Working on a project currently, running it through visual studio locally, and I'm having a problem editing the css. When I inspect the page in Chrome I can usually click in the styles area and change styles on the fly to check if they work before I add them to the css. However, what is currently happening is when I type something like:

```
clear:both;
```

I can type clear fine, but when I type the letter b it jumps the insertion cursor down into the console window, even if the console window is closed (it opens it). This means I can only type one letter at a time (or press the up or down arrow keys once for numerical values).

Has anyone else experienced this? It only seems to happen with this project.

Comment: I posted this exact problem on Super User a few days ago: http://superuser.com/questions/1062935/in-chromes-developer-tools-every-time-i-try-to-modify-existing-css-property-va. After coming back to my work PC after the weekend it appears to work normally again. My PC hasn't restarted, nor has Chrome. It's very peculiar.